# uCommerce Product Appears on Sitecore site without publishing

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8

Just started doing some development with uCommerce and Sitecore but the way products start to appear on a site seems odd.

In the Avenue Clothing demo site if you create a new product within the uCommerce admin it immediately starts to appear in the product listings, but if you click to view the product page a 404 is returned as the Sitecore items haven't been published yet.

Is this right? Is there's no way of adding / editing a product without it immediately taking effect on the website? Or have I got something configed wrong.

Also have a similar issue with removing products. The only way I can see is to delete the product through the uCommerce UI, but that leaves behind all the sitecore items.

Comment: Is this happening in all environments or dev only? Are you running locally in Live Mode (i.e. off the master database)? Are your search indexes running off the web or master database? I haven't used uCommerce unfortunately so can't help on the exact issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most recent version of the uCommerce to Sitecore connector runs in live mode, so your experience is currently by design as far as I know.

It is due to some performance issues on publishing. I would expect a fix to it but don't know of a timeline for it.

Answer (score 1):

I have used ucommerce on Umbraco projects and there was an option I think put in in 2013 to allow you to create with out publishing.  I cannot believe it's not in the current Sitecore one.  99%  It sounds like a configure thing for ucommerce. :)

Yep there was one https://ucommerce.uservoice.com/forums/23685-ucommerce/suggestions/3619522-save-without-publish

Answer (score 0):

While I haven't used uCommerce, this sounds like a classic indexing configuration issue. Typically, listings are driven off of an index file which is either pointed to synchronize with the 'master' database, or the 'web' database. You likely have your settings configured for an authoring environment.

In that scenario, indexes are often configured to pull from the 'master' database so that authors can review that their changes are showing up in product listings.

I would recommend searching for a uCommerce indexing configuration file and see which synchronization strategy is assigned. If it is 'syncMaster', that indicates the index will be updated immediately with every edit to the master database. You likely want one of the synchronization strategies that points at the 'web' database instead for your content delivery servers.

If you are running single-instance, I recommend running with the 'web' synchronization strategy and training your authors to understand that they won't be able to preview unapproved content in the listings.